# wxPython -- escaped ampersand still not displaying in Linux

Tags: linux, wxpython

I'm working on an app with a wx.StaticText object. I want to show an ampersand ('&'), so my label has '&&' to escape the hot-key shortcut. This is the agreed-upon solution, and it works when I run my app in Windows.

But in Linux (Ubuntu 12.04), I'm still missing the ampersand. Has anyone faced this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me on XUbuntu 14.04 with wxPython 2.8.12 and Python 2.7:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Amp")
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        txt = "The king && I"
        lbl = wx.StaticText(panel, label=txt)

        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

It produces the following:

[image]